# Time-series mixed effect model (lme4)

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to run a mixed effects model that uses time as a fixed effect. I have repeated measures taken over irregular time intervals (3-7) and want to account for the fixed linear relationship my variables have with time. At the same time I am interested in determining treatment effects (drought and competition).

Below is one of my datasets I am trying to run this on using `lme4` and `lmer`

```
> BRCAgassydays
   Species Drought Competition Treatment Time assimilation conductance intercellularcarbon
1     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI    0     7.811799  0.16297273            297.5562
2     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   21     5.405663  0.19472180            314.8806
3     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   29     7.604270  0.14460617            291.1411
4     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   34     7.513887  0.22543327            326.1150
5     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   42     6.683802  0.18940180            318.6928
6     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   55     6.071712  0.13774260            301.6228
7     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   70     6.331053  0.13962460            306.8503
8     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   78     4.941679  0.13157067            312.1904
9     BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   82     4.729761  0.11871700            313.6009
10    BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   88     6.831296  0.16134250            305.1969
11    BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI   97     4.652050  0.09225767            295.9346
12    BRCA Control    Invasive       CxI  104     5.873223  0.16265633            313.8243
13    BRCA Control        None       CxN    0     7.644604  0.17184619            301.8665
14    BRCA Control        None       CxN   21     8.250492  0.23745253            317.0501
15    BRCA Control        None       CxN   29     7.463330  0.13094473            286.2365
16    BRCA Control        None       CxN   34     7.928604  0.24988353            328.3139
17    BRCA Control        None       CxN   42     7.415549  0.18531760            309.8957
18    BRCA Control        None       CxN   55     6.764483  0.13508080            291.4254
19    BRCA Control        None       CxN   70     5.666392  0.11958453            304.4248
20    BRCA Control        None       CxN   78     7.267130  0.16822320            303.4725
21    BRCA Control        None       CxN   82     5.870902  0.11838573            297.4116
22    BRCA Control        None       CxN   88     7.400286  0.18886560            306.0608
23    BRCA Control        None       CxN   97     5.397562  0.13183013            313.4487
24    BRCA Control        None       CxN  104     5.756836  0.14453173            311.5725
25    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI    0     6.932256  0.12224355            285.7301
26    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   21     8.448956  0.22943413            311.6504
27    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   29     7.410476  0.12434440            280.5574
28    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   34     8.208636  0.26668580            327.9786
29    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   42     5.324922  0.12691907            312.5066
30    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   55     5.196439  0.10962533            295.7930
31    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   70     4.643326  0.08082647            289.0008
32    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   78     3.675965  0.07471427            298.9459
33    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   82     4.113252  0.09586540            310.3563
34    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   88     4.340185  0.09807740            310.9444
35    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI   97     4.410509  0.09351200            304.7900
36    BRCA Drought    Invasive       DxI  104     2.961152  0.06973620            309.7580
37    BRCA Drought        None       DxN    0     5.299206  0.10402717            299.4199
38    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   21     8.931698  0.22541307            310.6568
39    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   29     6.490820  0.10163740            271.2123
40    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   34     6.748470  0.19204680            323.1626
41    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   42     4.175082  0.08008673            295.1853
42    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   55     4.740064  0.10071627            293.5214
43    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   70     5.147252  0.09366540            284.0992
44    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   78     5.187626  0.09444033            291.6765
45    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   82     4.608225  0.09833660            303.1695
46    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   88     6.398861  0.14120963            303.1060
47    BRCA Drought        None       DxN   97     3.980145  0.11448827            324.5742
48    BRCA Drought        None       DxN  104     5.233092  0.12851007            313.0436
   transpiration        seA        seG     seCi       seE
1       2.822450 0.43644138 0.05761956 105.2020 0.9978866
2       2.320922 0.45469707 0.08708224 140.8189 1.0379479
3       1.790830 0.47508738 0.05903522 118.8578 0.7311035
4       2.400032 0.43793202 0.10081682 145.8431 1.0733268
5       2.805418 0.67185683 0.08470306 142.5237 1.2546211
6       3.114693 0.74197040 0.06160036 134.8898 1.3929330
7       1.795997 1.23465637 0.06244202 137.2276 0.8031942
8       2.715327 0.72150617 0.05884019 139.6158 1.2143311
9       2.544619 0.74568747 0.05309186 140.2466 1.1379881
10      3.019007 1.51528270 0.08067125 152.5985 1.5095034
11      1.784082 0.03402206 0.04612883 147.9673 0.8920409
12      3.453956 0.33488091 0.07274212 140.3465 1.5446562
13      2.598881 0.46217235 0.06075680 106.7259 0.9188432
14      2.909069 0.84976554 0.10619200 141.7891 1.3009752
15      2.025599 0.50776426 0.05856027 128.0088 0.9058755
16      2.487442 0.54267771 0.11175131 146.8264 1.1124180
17      2.875295 0.11954494 0.08287655 138.5896 1.2858709
18      3.265247 0.84720688 0.06040997 130.3294 1.4602628
19      1.483867 0.44247329 0.05347983 136.1429 0.6636057
20      3.203109 0.74145804 0.07523170 135.7170 1.4324737
21      2.539916 1.02080831 0.05294371 133.0065 1.1358850
22      3.553893 0.34056152 0.08446326 136.8745 1.5893495
23      1.926768 0.80018829 0.05895623 140.1785 0.8616768
24      3.047124 0.42481340 0.06463656 139.3395 1.3627154
25      1.899871 0.55859666 0.04321962 101.0208 0.6717057
26      2.797467 0.88094476 0.10260606 139.3743 1.2510653
27      2.110417 0.64763904 0.05560851 125.4691 0.9438074
28      2.689897 0.42303271 0.11926552 146.6765 1.2029587
29      2.197370 0.97036269 0.05675993 139.7572 0.9826938
30      2.669697 0.54886662 0.04902594 132.2827 1.1939247
31      1.295458 0.61865489 0.03614669 129.2451 0.5793462
32      1.736331 0.69632750 0.03341324 133.6927 0.7765110
33      2.171248 0.58167406 0.04287231 138.7956 0.9710117
34      2.127337 1.02370322 0.04386155 139.0585 0.9513742
35      1.719165 0.61438695 0.04181984 136.3062 0.7688341
36      1.628725 1.18038670 0.03118698 138.5280 0.7283880
37      1.572679 0.73317733 0.03677916 105.8609 0.5560261
38      2.887991 0.75700712 0.10080779 138.9300 1.2915488
39      1.712095 0.86022203 0.04545363 121.2898 0.7656720
40      2.074472 0.31120772 0.08588594 144.5227 0.9277320
41      1.466688 0.40419493 0.03581588 132.0109 0.6559227
42      2.380746 0.70855853 0.04504168 131.2668 1.0647018
43      1.520280 0.62697587 0.04188844 127.0530 0.6798899
44      1.772095 0.45202487 0.04223500 130.4417 0.7925049
45      2.191443 0.55772642 0.04397746 135.5815 0.9800431
46      2.756795 1.13005016 0.06315087 135.5531 1.2328762
47      2.051825 0.83631901 0.05120071 145.1540 0.9176041
48      2.867810 1.07582755 0.05747145 139.9974 1.2825237
```

I am having a hard time figuring out if I have coded it correctly:

`brcalme <- lmer(assimilation ~ Competition*Drought + (1|Time), data = BRCAgassydays)`

I am also having a hard time interpreting the results and determining whether they are significant without a p-value

```
> brcalme
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: assimilation ~ Competition * Drought + (1 | Time)
   Data: BRCAgassydays
REML criterion at convergence: 147.2326
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Time     (Intercept) 1.0027  
 Residual             0.9269  
Number of obs: 48, groups:  Time, 12
Fixed Effects:
                   (Intercept)                 CompetitionNone  
                        6.2042                          0.6980  
                DroughtDrought  CompetitionNone:DroughtDrought  
                       -0.7320                         -0.5918  


 summary(brcalme)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: assimilation ~ Competition * Drought + (1 | Time)
   Data: BRCAgassydays

REML criterion at convergence: 147.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3906 -0.4165  0.0132  0.5943  2.0888 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Time     (Intercept) 1.0055   1.0027  
 Residual             0.8591   0.9269  
Number of obs: 48, groups:  Time, 12

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                      6.2042     0.3942  15.739
CompetitionNone                  0.6980     0.3784   1.845
DroughtDrought                  -0.7320     0.3784  -1.935
CompetitionNone:DroughtDrought  -0.5918     0.5351  -1.106

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CmpttN DrghtD
CompetitnNn -0.480              
DroghtDrght -0.480  0.500       
CmpttnNn:DD  0.339 -0.707 -0.707
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can compare models (with and without effects) using anova. I think it will automatically refit the models using ML instead of REML.

Comment: Maybe this is a post best publised in 
Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "I am trying to run a mixed effects model that uses time as a fixed effect. I have repeated measures taken over irregular time intervals (3-7) and want to account for the fixed linear relationship my variables have with time."
No you have not coded it correctly. `(1|Time)` is a random effects term (see these references: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)

This random effects term is to group data points in your "repeated-measures". For example if you survey 20 different sites multiple times you might use `(1|Sites)` as a random effects term (see lme4 vignette link above for syntax help). If you really do have repeated-measures it would be good to group your data this way (helps avoid pseudo-replication).

For Time, you can fit it as a fixed effect:

```
brcalme <- lmer(assimilation ~ Competition*Drought + Time, data = BRCAgassydays)
```

But here you might get an error because you haven't specified any random effects (Time is a fixed effect in the equation above). So, all you need is a linear model (not mixed-effect). You can change `lmer` to `lm` to do this:

```
brcalme <- lm(assimilation ~ Competition*Drought + Time, data = BRCAgassydays)
```

But again, fit random effects terms if you can / is appropriate (but based on your question, I am guessing Time is not what you want as a random effects term).

Regarding p values, it would be worth reading up on what these really mean (e.g., [P-value, significance level and hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921661/p-value-significance-level-and-hypothesis), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166323/misunderstanding-a-p-value), and trying to learn to interpret your estimates and SE around those estimates (the magnitude of effects) rather than looking for 'statistical significance'. There is a reason that lme4 doesn't come with p value capabilities out of the box (i.e., you have to load `lmerTest`).

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for your detailed response I really appreciate it. I just learned a couple days ago too that I had coded the fixed effect wrong and that its more like a covariate. I don't have a random blocking factor for this experiment since the placement of my plants were randomized every week and I am analyzing species separately, but if I follow correctly, species identity could be used as a random effect if I ran the model as a whole. I am going to look a little more into these resources and play around with it some more, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the coding/instructions for the `lmer()` function, you do have valid inputs. If they are correct or useful depends ultimately on the theory you are using/testing. For such subject matter-specific or theoretical questions, look at CrossValidated.

Regarding how to obtain the p-values, load the package `lmerTest` and then run `summary()` on the model.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

lmm <- lmer(assimilation ~ Competition*Drought + (1|Time), data = brcalme)
summary(lmm)
```

**Output:**

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: assimilation ~ Competition * Drought + (1 | Time)
   Data: brcalme

REML criterion at convergence: 147.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3906 -0.4165  0.0132  0.5943  2.0888 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Time     (Intercept) 1.0055   1.0027  
 Residual             0.8591   0.9269  
Number of obs: 48, groups:  Time, 12

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      6.2042     0.3942 23.4989  15.739 5.61e-14 ***
CompetitionNone                  0.6980     0.3784 33.0000   1.845   0.0741 .  
DroughtDrought                  -0.7320     0.3784 33.0000  -1.935   0.0617 .  
CompetitionNone:DroughtDrought  -0.5918     0.5351 33.0000  -1.106   0.2768    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CmpttN DrghtD
CompetitnNn -0.480              
DroghtDrght -0.480  0.500       
CmpttnNn:DD  0.339 -0.707 -0.707
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! Should I remove and post this in crossvalidated instead then? the main question I have about the construction of my lmer, is whether or not `(1|Time)` is correct syntax to account for `Time` as a fixed effect, thanks for showing me how to get the p-valules

Comment: Hi Justin, I am glad it helped. AFAIK, that is the correct syntax. I would not delete the post: it is useful for people trying to understand how to get p-values in lme4. But StackOverflow is good for programming, while CrossValidated is better for statistics/quantitative methods.